# I want to preserve my data during service restart, but my data is not in simple variable name-value or table format. How should I go about this?

Tags: java, android, service

I want to preserve data during service restart, which uses a arraylist of {arraylist of integers} and some other variables.
Since it is about 40-60 MB, I don't want it be generated each time the service restarts(it takes a lot of time); I want to generate data once, and maybe copy it for next service restart.
How can it be done?

Please consider how will I go about putting a data structure similar to multidimensional array(3d or above) into file, before suggesting writing the data in a file; which when done, will likely take significant time to read too.

Comment: maybe you write it into a file?

Comment: I will definitely try that, but I was already going to do it anyway, if there is no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing your data after generation to a file. Then on next service restart, you can simply read that from the file.

Comment: I will definitely try that, but I was already going to do it anyway, if there is no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need persistent data, then put it into database
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

or try some object database like http://objectbox.io/

Answer (score 0):

So you're afraid reading from the file would take along time due to its size, the number and size of the rows (the inner arrays).

I think it might be worthy to stop for a minute and ask yourself whether you need all this data at once. Maybe you only need a portion of it at any given time and there are scenarios in which you don't use some (or maybe most) of the data? If this is likely, I would suggest that you'll compute the data on demand, when required, and only keep a memory based cache for future demand in the current session.

Otherwise, if you do need all the data at a given time, you have a trade-off here. Trade-off between size on disk and processing time. You can shrink the data using some algorithm, but it would be at the expense of the processing time. On the hand, you can just serialize your object of data and save it to disk as is. Less time, more disk space.

Another solution for your scenario, could be, to just use a DB and a cursor (room on top sqlite). I don't exactly know what it is that you're trying to do, but your arrays can easily be modeled into a DB. Model a single row as you'd like and add to that model the outer index of the array. Then save the models into the DB, potentially making the outer index field the primary key if the DB.

Regardless of the things I wrote, try to think if you really need this data persistent on your client, maybe you can store it at the server side? If so, there are other storage and access solutions which are not included at the Android client side.

Answer (score 0):

### Thank you all for answering this question.

This is what I have finally settled for:

- Instead of using the structure as part of the app, I made this into a
  tool, which will prepare data to be used with the main app. In doing
  so, it also stopped the concern regarding service restart.
- This tool will first read all the strings from input file(s).
- Then put all of them into the structure one at a time.(This will be
  the part which I was having doubts, and asked the question about.
  Since all the data is into the structure here, as soon as program
  terminates, this structured data is unusable.)
- Now, I prepared another structure for putting this data into file,
  and put all this data into file so that I do not need to read to all
  input file again and again, but only few lines.
- Then I thought, why spend time "read"ing files while I can hard code
  it into my app. So, as final step of this preprocessing tool, I made
  it into a class which has switch(input){case X: return Y}.
- Now I will just have to put this class into the app I wanted to make.

I know this all sounds very abstract, even stretching the concept of abstract, if you want to know details, please let me know. I am also including link of my "tool". Please visit and let me know if there would have been some better way.

P.S. There could be errors in this tool yet, which if you find, let me know to fix them.

P.P.S.
link: [Kompressor Tool](https://github.com/kamalyesh/KompressorTool)